# Updating different dictionaries based on the value of a raidoButton?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to append different dictionaries based on what raidoButton is selected in the GUI.

Currently I can append a select dictionary however I am trying to create something that will check the value of the selected raidButton ( 0,1, or 2)
and then with that value check another dict for the name of the dictionaries that need to be append.

Note: My dictionaries are stored on files outside of the program in the same directory as the script.

Here is my code.

```
thislib = IntVar() # thislib is the variable for the raidoButtons
def append_notes(event=None):
    buttonValue = thislib.get()
    list_of_dicts = {0:vzt_notes, 1:rms_notes, 2:nsr_notes}
    dict_to_be_updated = list_of_dicts[buttonValue]
    e1Current = keywordEntry.get().lower()
    e1Upper = keywordEntry.get().upper()
    e2Current = root.text.get(1.0, END)
    answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Update Notes!","Are you sure you want update your Notes for "+e1Upper+" This cannot be undone!")

    if answer == "yes":
        dict_to_be_updated[e1Current] = e2Current 
        with open("%s" %dict_to_be_updated, "r+" ) as working_temp_var:
            json.dump(dict_to_be_updated, working_temp_var, indent = "")
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('...','That was close!')
```

When I get the below error I think its saying that during my `with open` statement it is trying to pass the content of the dictionary as a filename/path. I am not sure how to get around this. I just want to get the file name from list_of_dicts by using the raidoButton value as the index value.

```
with open("%s" %dict_to_be_updated, "r+" ) as working_temp_var:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '{\'dss\': \'# DSS: Decision Support Systems\\n# U
```

Maybe I cant do it like this but it would be nice to know if I can do something simaler. Otherwise I have to create a long `if: elif: elif: else:` kind of statement for each dictionary I add as a note storage location.

Comment: It's not clear why you are trying to pass a dict to the `open` function; that's for opening files.

Comment: `Daniel Roseman` I was trying to pass the name of the dict the `open` function. I can see from the error code it is passing the content if the dict instead of the name. I am trying to figure out how to pass the name. | also I just added the error.

Comment: Objects don't know their names. If you need to pass the name, then keep a separate list of names and look it up in there.

Comment: Objects may have _multuple_ names: `foo = [1, 2]; bar = foo`; now `foo` and `bar` refer to the same object. This is why objects knowing their own names is hardly implementable in the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the advise of `Daniel Roseman`, I was able to use a separate list to perform the function I was looking for.

Below is the solution to my question if anyone is interested.

```
# This is the variable that stores the value of the selected radioButton
thislib = intVar()

def append_notes(event=None):

    # This is getting the current value of the radooButton selected. Currently the posible values are 0,1, and 2.
    buttonValue = thislib.get()

    # This list is used during out "with open" statement below.
    list_of_current_keys=["vzt_keys","rms_keys","nsr_keys"]

    # This list is used during out "with open" statement below.
    list_of_current_dicts=["vzt_notes","rms_notes","nsr_notes"]

    # The two dictionaries and lists below are used in the below if statement in order to
    # update the correct dictionary and list based of the returned radioButton value.
    list_of_dicts = {0:vzt_notes, 1:rms_notes, 2:nsr_notes}
    list_of_keys = {0:vzt_keys, 1:rms_keys, 2:nsr_keys}
    dict_to_be_updated = list_of_dicts[buttonValue]
    keys_to_be_updated = list_of_keys[buttonValue]

    # This variable is getting the lower case version of the typed keyword in the keyword
    # search box. This lets us search the key value of the dictionary without
    # having to worry about case being an issue to see if the keyword already exist
    e1Current = keywordEntry.get().lower()

    # This is used to store the keyword in the format typed by the used.
    # So the user can decide on the case they want displayed in the keyword list.
    e1allcase = keywordEntry.get()
    # e2Current is where all the notes are displayed or typed. we get the notes that are
    # in the textbox to update or add to the selected dictionary as the keys : string value.
    e2Current = root.text.get(1.0, END)

    # This is a simple pop up window that will ask if you are sure you wish to update your notes.
    # currently I have not written a way to undo the last update so for now this message is to
    # warn you there is no going back if you hit the "yes" button.
    answer = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Update Notes!","Are you sure you want update your Notes for "+e1allcase+" This cannot be undone!")

    # This if statement will check take the currently selected dictionary & list and update them.
    # If the keyword does not exist in the selected dictionary then It will add the keyword:"notes".
    if answer == "yes":
        current_library = list_of_dicts[buttonValue]
        selected_dict = list_of_current_dicts[buttonValue]
        selected_libkey = list_of_current_keys[buttonValue]
        if e1Current in current_library:
            statusW.config(text = "Updating Keyword & Notes for the "+selected_dict+" Library!")
            dict_to_be_updated[e1Current] = e2Current
            with open(selected_dict, "r+" ) as working_temp_var:
                json.dump(dict_to_be_updated, working_temp_var, indent = "")
            statusW.config(text = "Update Complete")
        else:
            statusW.config(text= "Creating New Keyword & Notes for the "+selected_dict+" Library!")
            dict_to_be_updated[e1Current] = e2Current
            with open(selected_dict, "r+" ) as working_temp_var:
                json.dump(dict_to_be_updated, working_temp_var, indent = "")
            keys_to_be_updated.append(e1allcase)
            with open(selected_libkey, "r+" ) as working_temp_keys:
                json.dump(keys_to_be_updated, working_temp_keys, indent = "")
            statusW.config(text = "Update Complete")
    # This calles a function that will update the display
        update_kw_display()
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('...','That was close!')
```